# Magento how to reterive data after saving in observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I am using this method.

```
public function saveProductTabData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if (!self::$_singletonFlag) {
        self::$_singletonFlag = true;
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        try {
             $myFieldValue =  $this->_getRequest()->getPost('custom_field');
             $product->save();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
   }
}
```

I want to know where is the data being saved in database (table name) and how to retrieve it.

The value that I get in `$myFieldValue` is saved in which column of db.

In short i want to make a dropdown of yes/no in custom tab of product edit admin page and then reterive the valuse (yes/no) which is selected after saving it.

Comment: in magnto 2 Varien_Event_Observer is not supported

Comment: What's an Input type of `custom_field` attribute ?

Comment: <select class="select" style="width: 185px;" name="custom_field" id="custom_field">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no" >No</option>
   </select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the value is not saved anywhere, because your observer only gets the value from the request and does nothing with it.
If you were to set that value on the product object, the value would be saved in one of the tables `catalog_product_entity_*` where `*` can be `int`, `decimal`, `varchar`, `text`, `datetime` depending on what type the attribute `custom_field` has.
But you should not care about that.
You can retrieve the value from the product object itself.

You can call later `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);` and get your value with `$product->getData('attribute_code_here')`.

Comment: In custom field i have used 
 
<select class="select" style="width: 185px;" name="custom_field" id="custom_field"> <option value="yes">Yes</option> <option value="no" >No</option> </select>